# Flutter retrieve Socket messages when App Idle or Inactive

Tags: android, ios, flutter, socket.io, pusher

I'm writing a chat app that uses Pusher. Messages are being sent successfully when the app is on screen, but when the application is running in the background, the socket closes itself after a while and stop receiving sender's messages.

What can I do to overcome this problem? It must be works on Android either iOS. If it's a bug related with pusher, I can convert my code to the socket.io too.

My code is below.
**pusher.dart**

```
class AppPusher {
  static final _appPusher = AppPusher._internal();

  AppPusher._internal();

  factory AppPusher() {
    return _appPusher;
  }

  final String _messaging = 'messaging';
  final String _notifications = 'notifications';

  PusherClient? _pusher;

  Channel? _channel;
  String? _channelName;

  final _pusherData = StreamController<SocketResult>.broadcast();
  Stream<SocketResult> get stream => _pusherData.stream;

  void connect({required Me me}) {
    if (_pusher == null) {
      final token = _getToken();

      _pusher = PusherClient(
        AppSettings.pusher.key,
        PusherOptions(
          cluster: AppSettings.pusher.cluster,
          encrypted: true,
          auth: PusherAuth(
            AppSettings.pusher.url,
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'},
          ),
        ),
        autoConnect: true,
        enableLogging: AppSettings.pusher.enableLogging,
      );

      _channelName = 'private-user-${me.id}';

      _channel = _pusher!.subscribe(_channelName!);

      _channel!.bind(_messaging, (event) {
        if (event != null) {
          _pusherData.sink.add(SocketResult<SocketMessage>(
            type: ChannelType.message,
            me: me,
            data: SocketMessage.fromJson(jsonDecode(event.data!)),
          ));
        }
      });

      _channel!.bind(_notifications, (event) {
        if (event != null) {
          _pusherData.sink.add(SocketResult<SocketNotification>(
            type: ChannelType.notification,
            me: me,
            data: SocketNotification.fromJson(jsonDecode(event.data!)),
          ));
        }
      });
    }
  }

  void disconnect() async {
    _pusherData.close();

    if (_pusher != null) {
      if (_channel != null) {
        await _channel!.unbind(_messaging);
        await _channel!.unbind(_notifications);
      }
      if (_channelName != null) {
        await _pusher!.unsubscribe(_channelName!);
      }
      await _pusher!.disconnect();
    }
  }

  String _getToken() {
    return locator<SharedPreferencesManager>()
            .getString(SharedPreferencesManager.accessToken) ??
        '';
  }
}
```

**app.dart**

```
void initPusher() {
  _pusher.connect(me: context.read<MeProvider>().me!);

  _streamSubscription = _pusher.stream.listen((event) {
    switch (event.type) {
      case ChannelType.message:
        context
            .read<ChatProvider>()
            .socketMessage(message: event.data, me: event.me);
        break;
      case ChannelType.notification:
        print('EVENT FROM NOTIFICATION: ${event.data}');
        break;
    }
  });
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    initPusher();
  });
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _streamSubscription.cancel();
  _pusher.disconnect();

  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: You can't keep a socket alive when the app isn't in the foreground. You should use a push notification to deliver message notifications and the retrieve the updated data when your app returns to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought about that too. but what if the user has turned off notification permissions?

Comment: Then they won't receive the notification.  You shouldn't use notification to deliver data anyway. Delivery of notifications aren't guaranteed. Your app should check with your server when it returns to the foreground.  You can't really implement a "serverless" chat system. (You can use cloud functions/lambda functions with a persistent store so you don't need a traditional dedicated server running 24/7)